# Writable Attributes in python

Tags: class, python-2.7

```
1. class Mine:
2.    def fun1(self,x):
3.        self.x=x
4.        print "Inside fun1",self.x

5.    def fun2(self):
6.        print "Inside fun2 :",self.x
7.
8.  obj1 = Mine()
9.  obj1.fun1(1)
10. obj1.fun2()

11. obj2 = Mine()
12. obj2.fun1(10000)
13. obj2.fun2()

14. del obj1.x
15. #obj1.fun2()
16. obj2.fun2()

17. Mine.a=111
18. obj3=Mine()
19. print "Mine.a: ",Mine.a
20. print "obj1.a: ",obj1.a
21. print "obj2.a: ",obj2.a
22. print "obj2.a: ",obj3.a

23. obj2.c=222
24. #print "\nMine.c: ",Mine.c
25. #print "obj1.c: ",obj1.c
26. print "obj2.c: ",obj2.c
27. #print "obj2.c: ",obj3.c
```

Can someone please help me to understand what is happening at line number 17 and 23, and why the code on line number 19,20,21,22 is working fine and code on line number 24, 25, 27 is giving error ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
17. Mine.a=111
```

you are adding a new static member `a` to the class `Mine`. the way python works (other object oriented languages do not do it this way) you can access `a` like it was a normal instance attribute; i.e. `m = Mine(); print m.a` will now work just as `print Mine.a`.

static members are normally added in the body of the class definition:

```
class Mine:
    a = 111
```

your second question:

```
23. obj2.c=222
```

this just adds a new member to the current instance `obj2`. neither the other insances of `Mine` nor the class `Mine` itself know about `c`.